# Google Cloud Run not scaling as expected

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm using Google Cloud Run to run a pretty basic Express / Node JS backend container. I receive fairly low number of requests per day, and only the occasional concurrent request.

However, I can see on my Cloud Run dashboard that Cloud Run sometimes scale up to 4 instances, most of the time to at least 2 instances. I know that my app load is so low that I'll pretty much never need more than 1 instance, so why is Cloud Run being so wasteful?

My settings is set as maximum 40 requests concurrently; minimum 0 containers and maximum 4 containers.

Container instance counts fluctuates substantially. Green line is idle containers and blue line is active containers.
[image: Container instance count]

My CPU usage is also very low:
[image: Container CPU utilization]

Comment: Not sure why was the question downvoted.
I have the same concern. Maximum concurrent requests are set to 80, still, it scales container as high as a provided number.
and it also throws 429 to API requests if it is not able to scale up more instances.
@Bruce C  Let me know if you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know your workload profile and the expected request. Cloud Run autoscaler does not. Therefore, it over provisions additional instances in case of traffic spike.

Of course, YOU know that will never happen, but IT doesn't.

Cloud Run is pretty well designed for average traffic. If you are at one extremity of this standard usage (very low traffic or very high, very spiky traffic), yes, the Cloud Run autoscaler provisioning model doesn't work so well.

---

However, what's the problem? You pay only when a request is processed on an instance. If there are over provisioned and not used instances, you won't pay them. It's a waste of money for Google, not for you.

Your only concern could be for the earth and the resource saving, and you have absolutely right.